# Google Play Developer API: get Subscription: what is subscriptionId?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

In documentation for the Get API

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get

It states:

> subscriptionId  string  The purchased subscription ID (for example,
>   'monthly001').

However, I can not find exactly that name in any of the Json returns of the Google's Billing Client.

I see: productid field (and a corresponding getSKU method) in SkuDetails.java (part of billing client)

```
 /** Returns the product Id. */
  public String getSku() {
    return mParsedJson.optString("productId");
  }
```

But there is no subscriptionId.
Is productId in SkuDetail the right value for the 'subscriptionId' that the API above expects?

Comment: Yes, `productId`. I think `productId` is the general term, when referring to subscriptions in particular, it is `subscriptionId`.

Comment: thank you, if you post this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted and answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `productId`. I think `productId` is the general term; when referring to subscriptions in particular, it is `subscriptionId`.

Happy coding :)